# Render a 'micropost feed' from the Rails Tutorial in a custom location/view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, custom-routes

I followed Michael Hartl's 'Rails Tutorial' book and need to render the 'micropost feed' at a custom location (/members) instead of at the site's root.

I've updated the SessionsController so that when a user logs in they are redirected to the new /members URL, but there are two statements needed on the member view that cause errors and prevent the page from loading with the micropost feed.

```
# app/views/members/index.html.erb
<%= render 'shared/micropost_form' %>
<%= render 'shared/feed' %>
```

The first error is:

```
ArgumentError in MembersController#index
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

returning `raise ArgumentError, "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty" unless object` 
and the second error (seen when removing the first render statement) returns `undefined method 'any?' for nil:NilClass`

Part of this issue is because to render the 'micropost feed' at `/members` the `app/views/members/index.html.erb` seems to need access to `app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb` and I'm unsure how to handle this.

**Update:**

micropost_controller.rb

```
# controllers/micropost_controller.rb

class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy

  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      redirect_to '/members'
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render '/members'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @micropost.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Micropost deleted"
    redirect_to request.referrer || '/members'
  end

  private

    def micropost_params
      params.require(:micropost).permit(:content, :picture)
    end

    def correct_user
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to '/members' if @micropost.nil?
    end
end
```

_micropost_form.html.erb

```
# shared/_micropost_form.html.erb

<%= form_for(@micropost, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new micropost (420 chars max)..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <span class="picture">
    <%= f.file_field :picture, accept: 'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png' %>
  </span>
<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#micropost_picture').bind('change', function() {
    size_in_megabytes = this.files[0].size/1024/1024;
    if (size_in_megabytes > 5) {
      alert('Maximum file size is 5MB. Please choose a smaller file.');
    }
  });
</script>
```

_feed.html.erb

```
# shared/_feed.html.erb

<% if @feed_items.any? %>
  <ol class="microposts">
    <%= render @feed_items %>
  </ol>
  <%= will_paginate @feed_items %>
<% end %>
```

MembersController (as updated with @Mandeep's suggestion below)

```
class MembersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build
    @feed_items = current_user.microposts
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you please post the code for controller, and partials?

Comment: Don't you have `index` method in your controller whose view you are rendering?

Comment: Second thing: You wrote the code for `MicropostsController`, and you are expecting something in `app/members/view/index.html.erb`. For the view of `members`, you should use `MembersController`.

Comment: And please post the code for you `index` method in controller. In `index` method, you should have `@micropost`, and `@feed_items` instance variables.

Comment: I added the `index` method from the MembersController as asked.  It was empty before, but I applied @Mandeep's suggestion earlier.  Thanks so much for both of your help!

Comment: you are welcome for it. Happy learning!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing arguments in your partials. You need to do the following:

```
<%= render 'shared/micropost_form', :locals => { :micropost => @micropost }  %>
<%= render 'shared/feed', :locals => { :feed_items => @feed_items }  %>
```

Remember, you need to have these two variables inside your `index` method: `@micropost` and `@feed_items`.

Comment: Thanks Arslan, that's very good to know!  Somehow I'm still getting the `raise ArgumentError, "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty" unless object` error though from `ArgumentError in MembersController#index`.

Comment: Why are you writing the code inside `MicropstsController`, instead you should write a separate `MembersController` class, and write member-related code there.

Comment: Good point.  Thanks for the info Arslan.  The tutorial I was following was designed that way and I didn't want to change it in case I broke something else. :)

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to your Controller:

```
class MembersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build
    @feed_items = current_user.microposts
  end
end
```